# What software can open older Jasc PSP 9 files?

Tags: software-recommendation, corel-paint-shop-pro

I'm a long time (but occasional) user of PSP 9, and while it still does everything I need, I can no longer find any support, either paid or peer, for my once-a-year questions.

I have no problem buying a more supported package, but I'd like to be able to open or at least convert my existing library of files. I don't 'do' photo work, so something that's aimed mostly at retouching or color grading is not favored.

Do I have any good options? I'd prefer to buy rather than rent, if you know what I mean (-:

Of course, a fine alternative would be to find out that people here can answer PSP 9 questions!

Comment: I get that this isn't a design question, but it's aimed squarely at the very people who could answer it. I doubt any other forum has the specific expertise this asks for.  Failing that, could I at least ask if members here can answer PSP 9 questions?

Comment: Well I'm at a cross road with this question for several reasons.  1) Not really design related but we do allow some software recommendations.  2)"Advise" is not a good word in the SE Q&A format. 3) What are you looking to do overall, open, modify, convert? 4) What do you mean by "convert" as in, png, jpg, gif?

Comment: @Matt - My ideal would be to get PSP 9 support from fellow users. If that's not possible, I'd happily buy a more supported program such as PSP X7 or PS, but only if it can open my existing library of .pspimage files, which include vector and raster layers etc.

Comment: @DumbNic I bought my copy a few years ago on eBay for I think about $20. It was recommended as the 'last good version' i.e. before Corel took it over. (-:

Comment: "JASC Paint Shop Pro 9" on eBay finds two copies for less than US$13 each, with free shipping...

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what kind of work you *do* create, but you may find that Photoshop Elements is more than adequate for your purposes, for all that it skews toward amateur photographers. It's a surprisingly powerful, vastly under-rated program, and has been since its early versions.

Failing that, you can find older versions of Photoshop for sale on eBay (be careful -- you don't want a pirated or cloned copy) or craigslist (be even more careful). Any version later than 7 will more than suffice as far as functionality goes, but you'll have to be alert to which versions are compatible with your OS.

PSP can save files as PSDs, which means you can then open them in any version of Photoshop or Elements.

Elements and Big Daddy Photoshop are both available as free trials. A couple of hours on lynda.com (using a week's free trial!) should be more than enough to give you the familiarity you need to make a choice.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My experience with saving PSP 9 files as PSDs is that vector layers are not preserved, or vector objects are either rasterized or lost when imported into PS. If that's not true, then Elements may well be what I need. I'll go looking.